# phpMyFaq won't export PDF in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: php, browser

Export functionality on my admin interface for phpMyFaq 2.7.3 version doesn't work for IE8. It works fine when I use Firefox. The format of the export document is PDF and the file is set to download. It works fine when I set the file to view-inline. It gives me TCPDF ERROR image error. Can you please help me with debugging this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Hey there, if you add some code and a bit more detail about the error (stack trace?) then its more likely somebody will be able to help you out.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that :

- phi.ini seems ok (memory_limit = 128M)
- rights seems ok (chmod 0777 /var/www/phpmyfaq)
- MYSQL BASE = UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I checked those and they are correct. still no luck.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Description: phpMyFaq PDF export file
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="2012-10-03-16-47-04_phpmyfaq.pdf"
content-transfer-encoding: binary
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.14
Set-Cookie: pmf_auth=ac98ecb2ac28a2a2b1af90e858c6505c; path=/
Last-Modified: Wed, 03 Oct 2012 14:47:17 GMT
Content-Length: 586976
Keep-Alive: timeout=60, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/pdf

Answer (score 0):

Did you already tried an upgrade to 2.7.8?